# Access JSON Data in Angular 2

Tags: angular, web-services, observable

I have a model of the following structure:

```
export class ExampleData{
    id: string;
    url: string;
}
```

I'm calling a service, that returns the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": "abc",
    "url": "/path/to/folder"
  },
  {
    "id": "def",
    "url": "/path/to/folder"
  }
]
```

The function for the call looks like this:

```
getExampleData(): Observable<Array<ExampleData>> {

    let headers = new Headers({'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    return this.http.get(Endpoint.Data, API_CONFIG.urls.urlToService, options)
        .do(console.log).map((response) => response.json());
}
```

In the console in my browser, the service call prints the result, and it works fine, i see the returned json. But when I want to access the content, it doesnt work. He doesnt even enter the forEach, because its empty.

```
forEach(this.exampleData, function (data) {
       alert(data.id);
    });
```

Comment: post your component code

Answer (score 0):

In your component, you have to `subscribe()` to your observable.

so it should look something like this.

```
//whatever your component is, somewhere ngOnInit or Onchanges

this.myService.getExampleData().subscribe(d => this.data = d);
```

you can also use `async` pipe if you are intending to only display on the html layer.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better if you'd provide your component snippet. You can try this:

```
 getExampleData():  Observable<Response> {

    //options & headers...

    return this.http.get(Endpoint.Data, API_CONFIG.urls.urlToService, options)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

Then on your component:

```
 exampleData: ExampleData[];

 this.dataService.getExampleData()
                 .subscribe(data => {
                  this.exampleData = data;
                  console.log(this.exampleData);
                  //Iterate through you data here
                 forEach(this.exampleData, function (data) {
                 alert(data.id);
                 });
            },
            error => {
       //Error
        }
      }
```